# HttpURLConnection не распознает deflate, как исправить?

Tags: java, android, deflate

Почему `HttpURLConnection` не распознает `deflate`.
`Браузер` распознал `deflate` и вывел содержимое.
А `HttpURLConnection` на `Java` выводит что-то типо этого `��N��310��1l��}�\���l�3�R�Ml���R�²ч+��`

Вот кусок кода:

```
HttpURLConnection c=(HttpURLConnection)new URL(Server).openConnection();
//c.setRequestMethod("GET"); // установка метода получения данных -GET
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
//c.setReadTimeout(5000); // установка таймаута перед выполнением - 10 000 миллисекунд
c.setDoOutput(true); //ПОСТ
c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
c.setConnectTimeout(5000);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()); //ПОСТ
writer.write(nameValuePairs.getString()); //
writer.flush(); //


c.connect(); // подключаемся к ресурсу
result[0]=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(), "utf-8")).readLine();
Voider.log("GETCONTENCOD", c.getContentEncoding());
```

`GETCONTENCOD` вывел `deflate`

в `result[0]` строчка `deflate` вида, если `deflate` на сервере нету то в `result[0]` обычный `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще так быть не должно. Вы не послали серверу `"Accept-Encoding: deflate"`, поэтому сервер не должен выдавать вам результат в `deflate`. Но раз уж такое дело, можно обернуть в [`InflaterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) или [`GZIPInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html):

```
InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
if("deflate".equals(c.getContentEncoding())) {
    is = new InflaterInputStream(is);
} else if("gzip".equals(c.getContentEncoding())) {
    is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
}
result[0]=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8")).readLine();
```

Comment: Сервер написан мною, и заголовки отсылаются, браузер все воспринемает и даже qt автоматом распаковал deflate, а вот java не желает

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, значит, вы коряво написали сервер, если он отдаёт клиенту deflate, когда клиент его не согласен принимать.

Comment: Нет не коряво, если заметили я написал что Voider.log("GETCONTENCOD", c.getContentEncoding()); возвращет deflate, и два клиента уже отлично читают deflate из сервера но не java

Comment: Или что-то теряется и java считает битой строку или что

Comment: Да я сейчас его попробую, распознать заголовок от сервера что это deflate уже умею, и сейчас попробую ваш способ

Comment: Говорит студия вот что, is = new InflaterOutputStream(is); is- InputSteam,  а надо OutputSteam

Comment: Вот что мне говорит adb, лог не вмешается может перейдем в обсуждение?

Comment: Коротко лог такой Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: data error

Comment: Возникает на строчке result[0]=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8")).readLine();

Comment: gzip на удивление заработал с помощью фитч if("gzip".equals(c.getContentEncoding())) {
                        is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
                    }

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, возможно, вы для "deflate" на самом деле генерируете gzip-поток на сервере. Браузеры могут быть умнее и смотреть на содержимое потока, а не только на Content-Encoding. Но, конечно, это не соответствует стандарту HTTP.

Comment: Да я заметил что мой хостинг творит не нежные мне чудеса, как например через апач создается gzip, который мне не нужен, как можно запретить gzip через еще один файл апача? А то у меня выходит что в начале робит файл конфигурации потом дополнительно работает мой файл конфигурации (.htassec или как его там). Это я заметил когда начел слать заголовок на сервер, когда эти заголовки должен разбирать мой скрипт а не апач.